# Em Dash and En Dash from MySQL Db with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying out output a MySQL database field with PHP which contains em dash and en dash, but although the ROWs output, the values with these dashes do not.

As far as I am aware, these are characters which should be used in proper english, therefore I don't think I should be stripping them out or replacing them with an alternative (like a hyphen).

By adding this code before the INSERT, I am able to get the em dash and en dash into the database properly (whereas without this line I saw unwanted characters instead):

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

But, the value won't output. The database table and it's fields are using the utf8_general_ci collation and I've got these lines in my PHP page:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I'm outputting the value like so:

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n\n", $row['someText'])));
```

If I output the value without formatting, I see this question mark character:

�

Does anyone know how to get around this? Am I forced to replace them with hyphens even though that's grammatically incorrect, or is there a way to output them as they appear in the database?

Comment: How certain are you that they're encoded as UTF-8 in the database?

Comment: In the front-end for the MySQL database it shows me the collation for the table and also for the column are both 'utf8_general_ci'. Is that what you mean, or is there more encoding elsewhere? If so, how can I check that? Thanks.

Comment: Cast it as bytes when selecting.

Comment: I ran "SELECT CONVERT(myText, BINARY) FROM myTable" and got "[BLOB - 32 B]" - is this what you meant?

Comment: Use the `HEX()` function on the data.

Comment: A field with only an em dash in it comes back as E28094, one with an en dash comes back as E28093. Forgive my ignorance, I appreciate your help, does this confirm anything?

Comment: That confirms that they're [properly encoded as UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the same MySQL command before retrieving data from the Db and this solved the issue.

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); // Use utf-8
```

I don't know *why* this is needed but I'll investigate and see if I can make this a default.

Comment: `mysql_set_charset()` is what you should use for that. I'm not sure you can set a default MySQL client encoding that PHP will listen to - calling `mysql_set_charset()` on every connection is the safe way.

Comment: What is the PDO version of this?